# How to change the type of columns of excel files for exported SheetJS xlsx?

Tags: javascript, excel, sheetjs

I want to convert a table into an xlsx file. I'm using [SheetJS](https://sheetjs.com/). It success to get data, create the file and download it.

The issue comes from excel types. For excel, all columns are simple string, and for example `23,0€` isn't recognize as money, and I can't do basic excel calcul as `sum` :

[image]

To fix it in excel, I should enable modification, try to edit then use enter to let it be recognized as money cell :

[image]

My code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Elikill58/1sxyzmdL/) (I can't add direct snippet into question as it require download).

All my excel manipulation:

```js
const worksheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(document.getElementById("myTable"));
const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, "Worksheet");
XLSX.writeFile(workbook, "Export.xlsx");
```

How can I change type in SheetJS to let excel recognize values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I should [override set the cell-type](https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/api/utilities/#value-override) myself, but as it's not a general format, it's different. ([example of the default one](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/blob/github/bits/10_ssf.js#L126))

1. **Get the cell type**. After making the real excel file (without issue) you can use:

```js
var XLSX = require("xlsx");
var wb = XLSX.readFile("export.xlsx", {cellNF: true})
var ws = wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]]
console.log(ws["A1"].z)
```

And you will see the type. In my case, it's `'#,##0.00\\ "€";[Red]\\-#,##0.00\\ "€"'`.

2. For each `<td>`, you should **add the given format** everything as :

```
<td data-v="100" data-t="n" data-z='#,##0.00\ "€";[Red]\-#,##0.00\ "€"'><p>100,00€</p></td>
```

- `data-v` will contains the value as, in my case, integer (without `€`)
- `data-n` is set as "n" because the value is a number
- `data-z` is what we get before: the formatting of the cell

3. Use same code to export the content, and everything will works.